# How to get a sum of counted objects using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a sum of objects that are counted in text file. For example, this is how my file looks like:

Total servers: 3
Total databases: 10
Total table spaces: 30

Total servers: 5
Total databases: 50
Total table spaces: 500

Total servers: 3
Total databases: 30
Total table spaces: 100

I will need to get the sum of databases, so it should be 90 total.

Comment: Where's the code? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You may start with the extraction of the numbers from text and turn them from strings to actual numbers.  I'd recommend watching this video: [Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU)

Comment: Did you notice that you actually already asked this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416910/how-to-count-objects-in-text-file-using-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416910/how-to-count-objects-in-text-file-using-powershell)

Comment: Olaf - this is different ask, I'm asking on how to count the sum of numbers in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (presuming your data is in a file called `list.txt`):

```
$dbCount = 0
Get-Content "list.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  $matches = [Regex]::Matches($_,'Total databases: (\d+)',"IgnoreCase")
  if ( $null -ne $matches.Groups ) {
    $dbCount += $matches.Groups[1].Value -as [Int]
  }
}
```

With your sample data in `list.txt`, `$dbCount` will equal `90`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the text file content as `$inputString`:

```
$array = $inputString.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
$regex = 'Total databases: (?<dbCount>)[0-9]+'
$sum = 0

ForEach $string in $array {
    $string -match $regex

    $sum = $sum + [int]$Matches.dbCount
}
```

References:

- [Split by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252620/powershell-split-specify-a-new-line)
- [Regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1)

`$sum` contains the value that you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, I'm getting this error parsing "Total databases: (?<dbCount>)[0-9]+)" - Too many )'s

Comment: Remove the last ")"

Comment: I removed ')' but as the result I'm getting "False" as an output.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
((Get-Content file.txt) -replace '^.*databases: (\d+).*$','$1' | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```